# Can not call backing bean method from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsf, primefaces

I try to write javascript code in bean method. I am successful at this in application start.

When I run my application, the js function calls the bean method and return values, however when I click to button it never calls again. I mean, It only calls the bean method while application is starting.
My button is:

```
<p:commandLink oncomplete="myRemote();" title="my button"
               />
```

My javascript function is:

```
 function myRemote() {
 ${myBackingBean.actionMyValues()}

 }
```

My Bean is:

```
@Controller
@Scope("view")
public class MyBackingBean implements Serializable {


public String actionMyValues() {

    String js="";
    /*getting some values from database and adding it to javascript variables.*/
    js += "alert('alert')";//
    return js;
}
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear for me, but why don't you consider using p:remoteCommand ?

Comment: My design is like writing the javascript code in client as string and passing it to client. This works once, when application runs. However, if I try to do it with button click, the content of javascript function does not change. Js function does not call bean method and so it does not get the new content of string.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to call JS from your backing bean you can use the `org.primefaces.context.RequestContext` class:

```
String js="";
/*getting some values from database and adding it to javascript variables.*/
js += "alert('alert')";
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("js");
```

**EDIT**

As it has been suggested in the comments you can also use a `p:remoteCommand` (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml)

The remote command would replace your custom JS function:

```
<p:commandButton value="My button" type="button" onclick="myRemote()" id="btnRemote" />  

<p:remoteCommand name="myRemote" actionListener="#{myBackingBean.actionMyValues()}"/>
```

Then if you need to call JS from your bean you still need to use the `RequestContext`.

Comment: As far as I can see , the question is the other way, calling server side method from JS.

Comment: Indeed but in the proposed code, the part that was executing JS from the server side was wrong. I made and edit, a better solution would be to replace the whole thing with a p:remoteCommand as suggested by Hatem

Comment: this is the other way round question\